# Oracle join tables using string functions

Tags: sql, string, oracle, join

I have to join table `CAMPAIGN` and `WF_ACTIVITY` such that `CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY = WF_ACTIVITY.PARAMETERS='CAMPAIGN_KEY='`.The `WF_ACTIVITY` table has Parameters column which contains value for example as :

```
CAMPAIGN_KEY=ROAMING_DATA_FLAT
STEP_KEY=START_COLLECTION
PARAM_KEY=BYPASS_PROVISIONING
```

I have to take only the value which has `'CAMPAIGN_KEY='` string from Parameters column and join it with `CAMPAIGN_KEY` column value from the `CAMPAIGN` table.I really dont know which string functions i can use or how do i trim the string part from Parameters columns which has value `'CAMPAIGN_KEY='` and comapre it.

Comment: Are you looking to join on, for instance, `CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY` is equal to `foo` and `WF_ACTIVITY.PARAMETERS` is equal to `CAMPAIGN_KEY=foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any special functions to achieve what you're looking for.

Setup:

```
create table CAMPAIGN (
  campaign_id number,
  campaign_key varchar(100)
);

create table WF_ACTIVITY (
  wf_activity_id number,
  parameters varchar(100)
);

insert into CAMPAIGN values (1, 'ROAMING_DATA_FLAT');
insert into CAMPAIGN values (2, 'ROAMING_DATA_ROUND');

insert into WF_ACTIVITY values (1, 'CAMPAIGN_KEY=ROAMING_DATA_FLAT');
insert into WF_ACTIVITY values (2, 'STEP_KEY=START_COLLECTION');
insert into WF_ACTIVITY values (3, 'PARAM_KEY=BYPASS_PROVISIONING');
insert into WF_ACTIVITY values (4, 'CAMPAIGN_KEY=ROAMING_DATA_ROUND');
```

Query:

```
select *
from CAMPAIGN c
join WF_ACTIVITY w on 'CAMPAIGN_KEY=' || c.campaign_key = w.parameters
where w.parameters like 'CAMPAIGN_KEY=%';
```

All this does it use string concatenation to append "CAMPAIGN_KEY=" before c.campaign_key.

Results:

```
CAMPAIGN_ID CAMPAIGN_KEY        WF_ACTIVITY_ID  PARAMETERS
----------- ------------        --------------  -----------
1           ROAMING_DATA_FLAT   1               CAMPAIGN_KEY=ROAMING_DATA_FLAT
2           ROAMING_DATA_ROUND  4               CAMPAIGN_KEY=ROAMING_DATA_ROUND
```

Comment: do i need to use where condition also ? because i have thousands of records and the Paramaters column is not indexed so in this case query performance will be slow.

Comment: @Rahul, no, technically you don't.  Get an explain plan both ways and use the one that performs best.

Comment: Thanks Mark its running fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29920820/1175077) you don't need to use any string functions, but if you do want to go that way you would probably want to use `substr`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CAMPAIGN C
JOIN WF_ACTIVITY WA ON SUBSTR(WA.PARAMETERS,14) = C.CAMPAIGN_KEY
-- the where clause is optional
WHERE SUBSTR(WA.PARAMETERS,0,13) = 'CAMPAIGN_KEY=';
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8184e/3)

Comment: do i need to use where condition also ? because i have thousands of records and the Paramaters column is not indexed so in this case query performance will be slow.

Comment: If using this approach, I think you'd want the substring to include the first 13 characters = 'CAMPAIGN_KEY=', otherwise you will have a problem if there are other parameters with similar names (such as 'CAMPAIGN_KEYS' or 'CAMPAIGN_KEY_LENGTH').

Comment: @Rahul No, you don't.

Comment: Thanks its running finw now :)